# How are the Javascript engine, runtime engine and callback queue linked?

Tags: javascript

I am having some problems understanding some terminology regarding the JS engine, JS runtime engine, event loop, callback queue and concurrency model work. I am reading different articles and they don't seem to be saying the same thing.

In this [article](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-does-javascript-actually-work-part-1-b0bacc073cf), from what I understood so far, the JS engine contains the call stack and the heap. The runtime engine then contains the JS engine, callback queue, event loop and web apis.

But in this [article](http://prashantb.me/javascript-call-stack-event-loop-and-callbacks/), it writes "V8, Chromes runtime engine comprises of a Stack and a Heap. ".

And finally in the Mozilla [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), it writes that the runtime consists of stack, heap and queue.

From what I also got from this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027845/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-engine-and-javascript-runtime-environm), JS engine parses and converts human code to machine code. JS runtime then executes the code for us.

I am quite confused right now, or maybe I am overthinking this.

- What does the JS engine consist of?
- What does the JS Runtime Engine consist of? Is it called runtime engine or runtime environment?

Comment: Any of these questions would be entirely implementation-dependent.

Comment: Does this help? [Stackoverflow Q 29027845](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027845/what-is-the-difference-between-%20javascript-engine-and-javascript-runtime-environm?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my previous comment I've just seen it is already in your question.