# Is the event-loop, queue, etc. part of the JavaScript runtime or engine?

Tags: javascript, runtime, v8, javascript-engine

I know that the `document`, `window`, etc. objects are part of the runtime, and I know that the engine deals with things like JIT compilation, running the actual code, etc.

But where does the event-loop, callback queue, etc. lie? Is it in the runtime? The engine?

Comment: similar question asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027845/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-engine-and-javascript-runtime-environm) - though the only mention of the event loop states it is in the "host environment not the JS implementation" - guess you could read that whole answer to see what they mean by those terms and how they relate to runtime and engine :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does V8 have an event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115031/does-v8-have-an-event-loop)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on this [article](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-does-javascript-actually-work-part-1-b0bacc073cf) which describes in detail, the Javascript Engine, Runtime and the call Stack

> The Engine consists of two main components:
>   * Memory Heap — this is where the memory allocation happens
>   * Call Stack — this is where your stack frames are as your code executes

[image]
Event loop and callback queue are part of Javascript Runtime:
[image]